# Problem converting 3-dimensional array to 4-dimensional array in images

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
import numpy as np
    arrs = [np.random.random((32, 32, 3))
        for i in range(50)]
arrs

>>>[array([[[0.65888998, 0.68624646, 0.74916052],
     [0.63448461, 0.01746295, 0.68938014],
     [0.93225555, 0.47979602, 0.37075014],
     ...,
     [0.8182584 , 0.87034063, 0.12904852],
     [0.74903229, 0.01573022, 0.32774447],
     [0.02755861, 0.32482874, 0.84268304]],

    [[0.89110809, 0.67637747, 0.8785393 ],
     [0.49642363, 0.76453882, 0.17271938],
     [0.53033236, 0.96183558, 0.11174256],
     ...,
     [0.80857021, 0.68966166, 0.73933673],
     [0.3486759 , 0.50314636, 0.31604295],
     [0.99832058, 0.42216604, 0.20958436]],


imgd = np.array(arrs)
imgd
>>> array([[[[6.58889978e-01, 6.86246462e-01, 7.49160524e-01],
     [6.34484605e-01, 1.74629524e-02, 6.89380136e-01],
     [9.32255552e-01, 4.79796022e-01, 3.70750142e-01],
     ...,
     [8.18258404e-01, 8.70340627e-01, 1.29048522e-01],
     [7.49032290e-01, 1.57302210e-02, 3.27744465e-01],
     [2.75586071e-02, 3.24828742e-01, 8.42683041e-01]],

    [[8.91108086e-01, 6.76377475e-01, 8.78539301e-01],
     [4.96423634e-01, 7.64538824e-01, 1.72719380e-01],
     [5.30332361e-01, 9.61835583e-01, 1.11742555e-01],
```

This code can convert successfully a list of 3d arrays into 1 4d numpy array but when I apply the same method in actual conversion of an image, it does not work.

```
data = []
directory = (r"C:\Users\-----")

for i in os.listdir(directory):
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(directory,i))
    data.append(image)
data

>>> [array([[[232, 240, 223],
     [232, 240, 223],
     [233, 241, 224],
     ...,
     [210, 216, 205],
     [211, 218, 205],
     [211, 215, 203]],

    [[230, 238, 221],
     [231, 239, 222],
     [232, 240, 223],
     ...,
     [213, 220, 207],
     [208, 215, 202],
     [210, 217, 204]],


np.array(data)
>>> array([array([[[232, 240, 223],
    [232, 240, 223],
    [233, 241, 224],
    ...,
    [210, 216, 205],
    [211, 218, 205],
    [211, 215, 203]],

   [[230, 238, 221],
    [231, 239, 222],
    [232, 240, 223],
    ...,
    [213, 220, 207],
    [208, 215, 202],
    [210, 217, 204]],

   [[230, 238, 221],
    [231, 239, 222],
    [231, 239, 222],
    ...,
    [209, 214, 199],
    [210, 217, 202],
    [211, 218, 203]],
```

I have used np.stack but it  does the same thing as the np.array.

Does this have to do anything with dtype='something' written at the end of every array of the output of the code which converts an image to an array ?

```
>>> [ 92, 113, 140],
    [ 94, 115, 142],
    [ 92, 113, 140]]], dtype=uint8),
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and construct a [example].

Comment: look at the definition of `numpy.concatenate` and the shapes of the arrays in the list

Comment: @scleronomic Got it! some images have different resolution

Thankyou!